# Parameterized Action Invoke Delegate

Tags: c#, winforms, delegates, action, invoke

I have the following working code sample:

```
public void ClearLogText() => this.TxtLog.Invoke((Action)delegate {this.TxtLog.Text = string.Empty;});
```

How would I properly add parameters?

```
public void SetControlText(Control control, string text) => this.Invoke((Action<Control, string>delegate (Control x, string y) {x.Text = y;});
```

The problem that I have is how to use the parameters into the function, in this case `control` and `text`.

Note: The method could have been anything. It is the concept that I care about, not what the method does. That was simply the first thing that came to mind.

Visual Studio complains about the obvious, namely that I am not using the arguments into the method.

I already know how to work with `Actions`, such as illustrated by [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11172089/action-multiple-parameters-syntax-clarification) answer. What throws me off is the `Invoke` and `delegate` parts.

```
private void NotifyUser(string message, BalloonTip.BalloonType ballType)
{
    Action<string, BalloonTip.BalloonType> act = 
        (m, b) => BalloonTip.ShowBalloon(m, b);

    act(message, ballType);
}
```

I would also like to keep the answer to one line using the construct `this.X.Invoke((Action)delegate...`, hence this question, otherwise the answer would be:

```
    public delegate void DelegateSetControlText(Control control, string text);

    public void SetControlText(Control control, string text)
    {
        if (true == this.InvokeRequired)
        {
            Program.DelegateSetControlText d = new Program.DelegateSetControlText(this.SetControlText);
            this.Invoke(d, new object[] { control, text });
        }
        else
            control.Text = text;
    }
```

Comment: What about doing `this.Invoke(delegate (Control x, string y) {x.Text = y;}, new object[] {control, text});`?

Comment: @juharr tosses `Error CS1660 Cannot convert anonymous method to type 'Delegate' because it is not a delegate type`. I always used to use the long method until a top coder at a company showed me the short version. He mentioned that the `Action` thing was necessary. I loved the simplicity of the statement even readability.  I wanted to extend that by adding parameters, just I am missing something obvious.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no need to include the `delegate` cast in the actual call.
The parameters go into the 2nd argument of the `Invoke` method, being a `params` object array, here containing `control` and `text`.

```
public void SetControlText(Control control, string text)
    => this.Invoke((Action<Control, string>)((ctrl, txt) => ctrl.Text = txt), control, text);
```